# Lagrange polynomials

Tags: interpolation, polynomials

I need to plot the 9 Lagrange polynomials associated to the points {−4, −3, −2, −1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4} all on the same axis.

So my attempt:

`

```
MakeBoxes[xlabel, TraditionalForm] := "x"
MakeBoxes[ylabel[n_], TraditionalForm] := 
 RowBox[{SubscriptBox["P", MakeBoxes[n, TraditionalForm]], "(", "x", 
   ")"}]
   Lagrange[l_List, max_] := Module[{n = Length[l], i, x},
  Plot[Evaluate[InterpolatingPolynomial[l, x]], {x, 0, max}, 
   DisplayFunction -> Identity, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   AxesLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ {xlabel, ylabel[n]}, 
   Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize[.03], 
     Point /@ Table[{i, l[[i]]}, {i, n}]}]
  ]
  pts = {-4, -3, -2, -1,0, 1, 2, 3,  4};
Show[Graphics[
  GraphicsGrid[
   Partition[Table[Lagrange[Take[pts, i], 9], {i, 2, Length[pts]}], 
    2]]], ImageSize -> 500]`
```

The problem is that I getting 8 lagrange polynomials, instead of 9, I have 9 points.
What am I doing wrong?

the result I got:
[image]

Comment: when i replace it to 1 here Partition[Table[Lagrange[Take[pts, i], 9], {i, 1, Length[pts]}], it ends on 8th polynomial, so the basic problem doesn`t disappear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MakeBoxes[xlabel, TraditionalForm] := "x"
MakeBoxes[ylabel[n_], TraditionalForm] := 
 RowBox[{SubscriptBox["P", MakeBoxes[n, TraditionalForm]], "(", "x", 
   ")"}]
Lagrange[l_List, max_] := 
 Module[{n = Length[l], i, x}, 
  Plot[Evaluate[InterpolatingPolynomial[l, x]], {x, 0, max}, 
   DisplayFunction -> Identity, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   AxesLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ {xlabel, ylabel[n]}, 
   Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize[.03], 
     Point /@ Table[{i, l[[i]]}, {i, n}]}]]
pts = {-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
Show[Graphics[
  GraphicsGrid[
   Partition[Table[Lagrange[Take[pts, i], 9], {i, 1, Length[pts]}], 
    3]]], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

The issue is the wrong settings of partition and your table, each one truncating one of your plots.

Of course the first point if you intend it to be on the same line, will have to be fixed or specially taken care of in your initial Lagrange function.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @KostyaKomless you're welcome, don't forget to hit the check mark and the up vote arrow for accepted answers :)! Welcome to MMA stack exchange. I encourage to read and answer questions.

Comment: In my understanding, a LagrangePolynomial is a polynomial that has zeros at all the given abscissa except on where it is: 1